# Restsharp parsing names not supported by C# Json

Tags: c#, json, restsharp, json.net

Hi I'm making a web api client that returns stuff in json.
I'm using Restsharp that uses newtonsoft.json to deserialize json objects.

The problem is that the server returns an object with a property with **#Text** as name. Is there a way to make restsharp parse this?

Here is a sample:

```
image: [
{
 #text: http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/55125087.png
 size: small
}]
```

All the other properties are being parsed just right the only problem is this one, the property is a string type so no problem in here.

Regards

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

That JSON isn't valid; you need to put quotes around the #text key (so make it "#text") as well as both values (so "http://...png" and "small").